# AWS Unrecognizable Lambda Output Cognito error

Tags: amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-cognito

I recently started working with AWS. I have integrated AWS Amplify using cognito user pools for my user management(login&signup) and it went perfect(User pool gets updated whenever a new user registers). Now i have added an Cognito Post confirmation trigger to save the registered email into database and here is my trigger codevar mysql = require('mysql');

```
var config = require('./config.json');

var pool = mysql.createPool({

host : config.dbhost,

user : config.dbuser,

password : config.dbpassword,

database : config.dbname

});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

let inserts = [event.request.userAttributes.email];

context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; //prevents duplicate entry

pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {

connection.query({

sql: 'INSERT INTO users (Email) VALUES (?);',

timeout: 40000, // 40s

values: inserts

}, function (error, results, fields) {

// And done with the connection.

connection.release();

// Handle error after the release.

if (error) callback(error);

else callback(null, results);

});

});

};
```

whenever a user registers and confirms his email this trigger invokes and throws me this error
 **"Unrecognizable Lambda Output Cognito "**. Even though it throws me this error in the background my DB is getting inserted with new registered email, but i am unable to redirect my page due to this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Aravind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Replace `callback(null, results);` to `callback(null, event);`

**Reason:** You have to return the result that Cognito will use it for continue the authentication workflow. In this case, this is `event` object.